# MongoDB Cannot successfully extract "column" names from cursor/array

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, multidimensional-array

So, I'm trying to grab the names of the <s>columns</s> properties in my MongoDB <s>project</s> documents. I can't seem to find the method I need to relay the names back to me. Any help/advice is appreciated.

**My Code:**

```
$cursor = $collection->find( $query );
foreach ($cursor as $obj) {
print_r ($obj);
echo $obj;
}
```

**print_r Returns:**

```
Array ( [Favorite] => 1171 [Desc] => EGG [Name] => MyThing )
```

**Echo Returns:**

```
Array
```

I want to be able to extract "Favorite", "Desc" and "Name" but, anytime I go after those fields, I get the value instead.

Comment: yes, because "Favourite", "Desc" and "Name" are the keys of the array.  If you want to get the keys and use them as values, try something like the array_keys() function in PHP (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data  = iterator_to_array( $collection->find($query) );
foreach($data as $d)
   $names[] = array_keys($d);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are no columns in MongoDB. Every document is essentially a JSON object. Each document can have a totally different structure.

I don't use PHP, but I'd guess that objects get returned as PHP's associative arrays. So, use [appropriate PHP functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) to get field names **for this concrete document**. Again, you can't get "a list of columns" for the whole collection.

Comment: [oh but you can](https://github.com/AD7six/mongo-scripts/blob/master/listKeys.js)